# Как сделать чтобы фон был статичен, и не менялся при смене контента?

Tags: html, css

У меня сейчас к body прописан фон:

```
min-height: 100vh;
background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
```

И при этом, при смене контента фон тоже чуть сдвигается.
Мне нужно чтобы он был не двигался, и при смене контента никуда не девался.

Можете глянуть разницу на двух фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте свойство `background-attachment: fixed;` и уберите `background-size: cover;`, оно и меняет картинку в зависимости от размера окна браузера

Comment: Без cover оно уменьшилось, стало не на весь экран

Comment: Можно еще поиграть с `background-size`. Допустим, задать статичный размер фона, такой, как у исходного изображения.  Например, `background-size: 1920px 1080px;`